# BigQuery DTS from Cloud Storage fails

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a csv generated by an R script that's pulling Search Console data. The file is UTF-8 format and uploaded successfully into cloud storage.  I can manually import the csv into a BQ table but the data transfer fails.

The csv file looks like so:

```
"query","clicks","impressions","ctr","position","serp","positionRound","clickP"
"ltv in google analytics",1,1,1,1,"1",1,NA
"ga 360 training",1,1,1,7,"1",7,NA
"$-£ conversion",0,1,0,11,"1",11,0
"0845 converter",0,1,0,48,"5",48,0
"convers",0,2,0,52,"6",52,0
"conversion",0,2,0,97,"10",97,0
"conversion agency",0,2,0,91.5,"10",92,0
"conversion agency london",0,4,0,33.5,"4",34,0
"conversion company",0,2,0,84,"9",84,0
```

The failure message is:

```
Job bqts_5cdee1a8-0000-2b7c-88f4-f4030439e0f4 (table cwgsc) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.; JobID: 61357964004:bqts_5cdee1a8-0000-2b7c-88f4-f4030439e0f4
```

I'm not sure where to find the `errors[]` collection. I'm using the web UI rather than the command line to set this up.  I have clients who want to do this in the future who aren't command line savvy and prefer to use the web UI.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yep - exactly right.  I just solved it and came back to post my explanation.

Yes, it was the header row.  I changed the config like so:

[image]

I found this in stack driver.  I looked at BQ logs like so:

[image]

Drilling into the right section of the log, I found the clue I needed:

[image]

So happy days now it's working.

Thanks!

D

Comment: Was this a comment to my answer misplaced? 
If that was the case, I'm happy to know that it solved your problem and also could you please accept the answer if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have a problem with the insertion at the first row.
This might be due to the header row that specifies the column names:

If you are using the Schema auto detect, it shouldn't be a problem.
However, if you are specifying the schema, BigQuery will treat those column names as real values, not as the column names that they are, and that might cause type errors.

One way to solve that might be to use either use the [Schema Auto Detect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) or access the Advanced options and [skip the Header row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwv2o.png).

Also, you can see a more detailed error message at the Job History section and clicking on the failed Job.